# doubleboot uuntu/win10: GRUB not recognising the correct win10 partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, windows-10, grub

I have a windows10 ubuntu doubleboot on lenovo t450s thinkpad, and when the GRUB menu appears, I only have an option to load from Windows recovery partition, which upon selection, comes up with error message *".../File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)..." error: cannot load image*.

I have tried updating GRUB from ubuntu, but it does not help. Now the thing is, if I exit the GRUB, my Windows boots fine, and ubuntu boots fine with GRUB.

I assume the issue is not with booting really, it is more of a convenience thing, to have everything working from GRUB instead of having to go through multiple steps to be able to boot Windows 10.

Thank you very much for any help, and please let me know if you need any more details; I have done chkdsk from Windows and it seems to be fine. Both OS'es operate well when they are booted too.

Comment: I have very similar on my Lenovo G580: `grub` creates a menu entry `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)` and `/dev/sda2` is the EFI partition, but it always gives an error. Fortunately there is also the entry `System setup`, which takes me to the BIOS boot selection menu, where I can choose between Ubuntu and Windows. I have tried a few unsuccessful things to get direct boot to work: now I live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Download Iso [Bootable iso](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) and either burn to a cd or a bootable usb or install manually below.

[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) Ubuntu boot repair

**Manual install**

Open a Terminal in Ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

**launch Boot-Repair from either** :

the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.